# making numberpad smaller?

Tags: xcode4.5

As per screen :
[image: overlapping text field]
you can see that as soon as numberpad popping up. its overlapping the some text field, I have in the app. moreover its not having have done or return button so that I can make numpad go away. I have made button to make keyboard go away but I want some more professional way.

please suggest. how can I add return or done button with keyboard and if there is another possible way I can reduce the size of keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know it is not possible to make the keybord smaller but what you can do is make your view move up once you have tapped on a UITextField this code will help you with that

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-10,320,400);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Now to the next issue u have to dismiss the keyboard I like to make it so that the user can just tap the background and it will resign the first responder. You can do that like this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

In dismissKeyboard

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard 
{
   [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Dear RPS, thanks a lot for detail about the solution. but I didnt get the tap gesture part.

Comment: You can put the tap gesture part into the text field did begin editing part. when the textfiled is active and you press on the background it calls the dismissKeybord statement and it will resign the first responder of your textfiled

Comment: How about if I put under viewDidLoad, actually I tried this morning. Is that bad practice putting tap gesture in ViewDidLoad

Comment: I wouldn't know if it is bad practice to put it into the viewDidLoad but I have had it in one of my apps and it has been working fine. _if this answer helped you please indicate so by hitting the check mark_